# Ошибка при подключении БД через redbeanphp c помощью composer

Tags: php

Начал изучать php и столкнулся с проблемой, при подключении БД через redbeanphp c помощью composer, выдает ошибку, Class 'app\controllers\AppModel' not found
в строке 13 D:\OSPanel\domains\ishop.loc\app\controllers\AppController.php

```html
<?php

return [
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ishop;charset=utf8',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
];
```

```html
<?php

namespace ishop;

class Db{

    use TSingletone;

    protected function __construct(){
        $db = require_once CONF . '/config_db.php';
        class_alias('\RedBeanPHP\R', '\R');
        \R::setup($db['dsn'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
        if( !\R::testConnection() ){
            throw new \Exception("Нет соединения", 500);
        }else{
            echo "Есть";
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<?php

namespace ishop\base;

abstract class Model;{

    public $attributes = [];//в нем будет храниться массив свойств Model в котором он будет идентичен по полям базы данных из ЛЯМ
    public $errors = [];//хранятся ошибки
    public $rules = [];//для правил валидации данных


    public function __construct(){
        Db::instance();
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

namespace app\models;

use ishop\base\Model;

class AppModel extends Model{



}
```

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use ishop\base\Controller;


//подключаем и создаем подкласс Контроллера с базой, от которого будем плясать
class AppController extends Controller{

    public function __construct($route){
        parent::__construct($route);
        new AppModel();
    }

}
```

Comment: `use app\models\AppModel;`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я стесняюсь спросить как мне избавиться от ошибки для подключения в конструкте класса Db
Произошла ошибка: Исключения

Текст ошибки: Class 'ishop\base\Db' not found

Файл в котором произошла ошибка: D:\OSPanel\domains\ishop.loc\vendor\ishop\core\base\Model.php

Строка, в которой произошла ошибка: 13